# Getting error when I try to run my first appium test

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

Hi I'm trying run my robot framework test using appium-library

My code

```
*** Settings ***
Library    AppiumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Open App
    Open Application    remote_url=http://localhost:4723/wd/hub   platformName=Android     automationName=UIAutomator2    app=apk.apk
```

When I run this code I get an error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource
```

Meanwhile when I open my appium inspector this works:
[inspector configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaWer.png)
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywbte.png)